# OData-v4 - operating on an entity collection then performing a Function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, odata-v4

In my ODATA-v4 controller, I have the following code:

```
var fn = reportModelBuilder.EntityType<CurrentTestResult>()
         .Collection.Function("Breakdown").Returns<int>();
```

In the CurrentTestResultController.cs, I have the deceptively simple:

```
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Breakdown()
    {
    var count = dataService.GetAll()
                .Select(x => x.TestResultTypeId)
                .Distinct()
                .Count();

    return Ok(count);
    }
```

Essentially, for all the `CurrentTestResult` entities in the collection, it returns the distinct `TestResultTypeId` occuring in the set. *(This is a trivial operation, but I simplified a really life scenario that's much more complex)*

That was easy to do - but I can't seem to **first** filter the collection of `CurrentTestResult` it should operate on.

This request, which by default operates on all CurrentTestResult entities

localhost/app/odatareport/CurrentTestResult/Default.Breakdown

returns

```
{
@odata.context: "http://localhost/app/odatareport/$metadata#Edm.Int32",
value: 5
}
```

(A correct result, there's 5 distinct types)

However, this request, which tries to simply filter it down first - fails

localhost/app/odatareport/CurrentTestResult/Default.Breakdown?$top=2

returns

```
{
error: {
code: "",
message: "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The requested resource is not a collection. Query options $filter, $orderby, $count, $skip, and $top can be applied only on collections.",
innererror: {
message: "The requested resource is not a collection. Query options $filter, $orderby, $count, $skip, and $top can be applied only on collections.",
type: "Microsoft.OData.ODataException",
stacktrace: 
" at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateSelectExpandOnly(ODataQueryOptions queryOptions) at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, ODataQueryContext queryContext) at System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"
     }
  }
}
```

As far as I understand the ODATA pipeline, why this fails makes sense. The controller method will return an IQueryable and then the ODATA $filter, $top, etc.. will be applied.

I would like a function to operate on a set that's already been filtered down.

**Is what I am trying to do even possible?**

I get that the Breakdown method itself has .GetAll() in it, but there mut be a way to apply the filtering before the method -

Otherwise, this is all quite pointless....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1) ODATA has a `$count` endpoint (see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx) but there are two forms of `$count` - an endpoint `api/collection/$count` and a system query option `api/collection?$count=true`; you'd want the endpoint) that returns the count of a collection (which can be filtered with `EnableQuery`).  Treat your function as any other `GET` collection method and return the query you wish to have counted (in this case, distinct `TestResultTypeId`), then simply require a client to request its `$count` endpoint.

2) define an `ODataQueryOptions<T>` parameter for your action method and apply the options manually:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get( ODataQueryOptions<CurrentTestResult> queryOptions )
{
    // base query with ODataQueryOptions applied
    var query = queryOptions.ApplyTo( dataServcie.GetAll() ) 
        as IQueryable<CurrentTestResult>;

    // get distinct TestResultTypeId's and then count
    var count = query.Select(x => x.TestResultTypeId)
            .Distinct()
            .Count();

    return Ok( count );
}
```

I'm mobile right now so not able to test, but this should be close enough (if not accurate) to get you where you need to go.  Please let me know if there are any issues and I'll updated the answer.

Comment: It is very close indeed - I still have a problem though - I did as you said - when I step through the code, it applies the options - however, in the client, I get this: https://imgur.com/a/dU32b

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to remove the AllQueryOptions attribute - thanks again!

Comment: Excellent, no problem